# cake php views from belongsTo association

Tags: cakephp, view, models

i have two tables with the following columns, **guardians(id,student_no)** and **student(id,admission_no)**. student_no is ***foreign*** to admision_no. *students* has a **hasMany** association with ***guardians***, ***guardians*** has a **belongsTo** association with ***students***.
here are my models

**STUDENT**

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Guardian' => array(
        'className' => 'Guardian',
        'foreignKey' => 'student_no',
        'dependent' => true,
        )
  )
```

**GUARDIAN**

```
public $belongsTo = array(
     'Student' => array(
        'className' => 'Student',
        'foreignKey' => 'student_no',
        )
  )
```

**Guardian controller**

```
public function view($id = null) {
    if (!$this->Guardian->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid guardian'));
    }
    $options = array('conditions' => array('Guardian.' . $this->Guardian->primaryKey => $id));
    $this->set('guardian', $this->Guardian->find('first', $options));
}
```

**Guardian view.ctp**
 **(truncated to view only the associated student from within the Guardian model)**

```
<h3><?php echo __('Associated Students'); ?></h3>
<?php if (!empty($guardian['Student'])): ?>
<table cellpadding = "0" cellspacing = "0">
<tr>
    <th><?php echo __('Admission No'); ?></th>
    <th><?php echo __('First Name'); ?></th>
    <th><?php echo __('Last Name'); ?></th>
    <th><?php echo __('Gender'); ?></th>
    <th><?php echo __('Date Of Birth'); ?></th>
    <th><?php echo __('Join Date'); ?></th>
    <th><?php echo __('Form'); ?></th>
    <th><?php echo __('Student Class'); ?></th>
    <th><?php echo __('Middle Name'); ?></th>
    <th class="actions"><?php echo __('Actions'); ?></th>
</tr>
<?php foreach ($guardian['Student'] as $student): ?>
    <tr>`
        <td><?php echo $student['admission_no']; ?></td>
line(115)   <td><?php echo $student['first_name']; ?></td> 
        <td><?php echo $student['last_name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $student['gender']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $student['date_of_birth']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $student['join_date']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $student['form']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $student['student_class']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $student['middle_name']; ?></td>

    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

i can view associated parent details from students view with above similar code,
however in guardians view i get error for the associated guardian

**ERROR**:Warning (2): Illegal string offset 'first_name' [APP/View/Guardians/view.ctp, line 115]

and for three lines below it.what exactly is going wrong

Answer (score 0):

Do some debugging: `debug($guardian)`

In your `belongsTo` assocaition, a guardian can only have a single student, so you are iterating over the columns of that one single student, ie consequently the `$student` variable will be a string, hence the error.

See also **[Cookbook > Models > Associations > belongsTo](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#belongsto)**

Comment: debugging $gurdian shows it has all the related students,plus after editing a student, i can nolonger view that student since the id passed to view action changes.dont know why

Comment: If by _all_ you mean _one_... @Gordon